# Set World Position of Child

Tags: three.js

I import an obj file with the OBJLoader. After then i want to change the position of a child from the imported model.
I try to get the position of the child with the following code:

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
vector.setFromMatrixPosition( child.matrixWorld );
console.log('vector', vector);
```

But it always return

```
THREE.Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}
```

How can i get the current world position of the child and then change it?

Comment: Try calling `model.updateMatrixWorld( true )` for the parent model prior to calling `setFromMatrixPosition()`.

Comment: I still got


    THREE.Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}

Comment: Maybe the child is at 0,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render the scene once before you get the position.

Use this line of code before you get the position :

```
renderer.render(scene,camera);
```

(here I assume the name of your scene and camera are scene and camera)

Here is an example of loading an object and getting the position :

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
objLoader.setPath( 'models/' );
objLoader.load( objFile, function ( child ) {
    child.position.z = 20;
    scene.add( child );
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
    vector.setFromMatrixPosition( child.matrixWorld );
    console.log('vector', vector);
}, onProgress, onError );
```

Here if you comment "renderer.render(scene,camera);", you will get :

Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 0}

and if you uncomment it you will get :

Vector3 {x: 0, y: 0, z: 20}